# VS and debugging into a nuget

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, nuget, devops

I have a solution that depends on a nuget package. The nuget package is created during the build process on the Devops server and configured to include the symbols package (see image) and it's pushed to the artifact feed on the devops server.

I have installed Visual Studio 2019 and I am trying to debug into the nuget package but without success. Should this work out of the box since the symbols are contained within the nuget itself or do I still need a separate Symbol server?

[image]

Comment: Can you open the `nupkg` and check if the `pdb` files are really there?

Comment: Hi @ShaykiAbramczyk the pdb files are not in the nupkg. Should the pdb files be included automatically during the build or is there something extra I need to do for them to be included in the package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add the publish symbols build step as explained here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/symbols?view=azure-devops